# Is it possible to use .NET Native without UWP?

Tags: c#, .net

Can a C#/.NET application be compiled to native binaries using .NET Native without being a UWP application? For example, a 4.5 console app? I've watched over 2 hours of video on .NET Native and also read docs but they did not clearly answer this question.

Comment: Not yet, unfortunately

Comment: Is there any info on this as a planned future capability?

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2014/04/02/announcing-net-native-preview/  `Today’s preview supports Windows Store applications. We will continue to evolve and improve native compilation for the range of .NET applications.`  No ETA though

Comment: Very helpful comment, thanks. It's funny how there are these little pieces of info that get confirmed rather than by a direct posting, by a lack of any current one.

Comment: The .NET Native command line tooling can be used unofficially for other project types (if you do Google search carefully), but still like others commented, you should wait till Microsoft officially announces that.

Comment: A good packaging solution that can guarantee that *all* code is present and accounted for at build time is a necessary and welcome next step.  Only UWP has it right now, it is not exactly perfect yet.  Reflection is painful enough with .NET Native, the only reason you have it on your machine so you can test it.

Comment: There is now some documentation on how to do this with the preview bits of **Microsoft.DotNet.ILCompiler** and .NET Core: https://github.com/dotnet/corert/tree/master/samples/WebApi

Answer (score 7):

There are not a perfect solution for this but serveral alternatives:

1. [Native AOT](https://github.com/dotnet/runtimelab/tree/feature/NativeAOT), formerly called 'Core RT', which supports full native compilation from managed dlls to binary executables on the target platform(OS and CPU Arch), but it is still marked as 'experimental' (Update: merged into the mainline since .NET 7 preview, [referring to the official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/deploying/native-aot/)) with a lot of features missing.
2. [IL2CPP](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/IL2CPP.html), which is developed and used only by Unity.
3. [CrossGen](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/Documentation/building/crossgen.md), which is a part of CoreCLR and could generate .ni.dll files which contains precompiled (native code on specific platform) code rather than IL code in normal managed dll, making it faster loading. But it still requires the runtime because it is basically still a managed dll with JIT compilation already done (AOT).

Note that .NET Framework is going to be obsolete with .NET Core becoming the unified .NET, and you can easily hear from some news about native compilation support if you keep watching [.NET Core things](https://github.com/dotnet/core)

Comment: How about .NET libraries? Can I write a native library in C# that does not depend on the .NET runtime and exposes a C ABI that can be consumed by native apps?

Comment: @EmileCormier Yes, the experiemental support for native library is added in .NET 7 preview, and you can export native symbols which could be accessed directly with `dlopen` and `dlsym`.

Comment: Regarding Native AOT, you wrote "Update: merged into the mainline since .NET 7 preview" -- can you please give a hint how and where to find it in net7?  On their github page (that you linked to) it still says "This repo is for experimentation and exploring new ideas that may or may not make it into the main dotnet/runtime repo."

Comment: @MikeNakis The question is updated with a link to the official docs

Comment: @MikeNakis The repo is actually obsoleted without being archived. it might be misleading.